# New MessagingStyle on API < 24

Tags: android, notifications

I just stumbled upon the new `MessagingStyle` described here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html (last paragraph)

I investigated further and found such a class also as a `NotificationCompat.Style` variant.

This is the code I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .notify(123, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Test")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentText("4 new messages")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("Me")
                                .setConversationTitle("Team lunch")
                                .addMessage("Hi", 123, null) // Pass in null for user.
                                .addMessage("What's up?", 234, "Coworker")
                                .addMessage("Not much", 345, null)
                                .addMessage("How about lunch?", 456, "Coworker")).build());
    }
}
```

This is basically just the default Activity generated when creating a new project and the sample code taken from the linked website.

Now my problem: The extended style is not shown on APIs below 24. I tested on a device with API 23. When running on an emulator with API 24, it works.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.html) states:

> Helper class for generating large-format notifications that include multiple back-and-forth messages of varying types between any number of people. 
>   If the platform does not provide large-format notifications, this method has no effect. The user will always see the normal notification view. [...]

But versions since KitKat do provide large-format notifications.

Is the documentation not clear enough or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** this is fixed as of the 25.0.0 Support Library release and `NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle` now backports much of the styling to previous versions of Android.

*Previous answer*:

As per [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218133), `MessagingStyle` currently does not do any special formatting prior to Android N. The bug report is marked as `FutureRelease` which means that the work is done and it **will** support pre-N devices with a more rich formatting in a future version of the Support Library.

If you wish to use it now, you can certainly build your own pre-N version of the notification (using a `BigTextStyle` if the version of Android is less than N for example).

Comment: The fix has been released in version 25.0.0 of the support libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-7.0.0_r6/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.java) correctly, the fallback for pre-24 devices has not been implemented as of the time of this writing. So, at the moment, it gives you something that compiles, and delegates properly to the native implementation on API Level 24+ devices, but will not show the messages on older devices.

Answer (score 1):

Additional note: check your imports and make sure you use the `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat` class
instead of `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat`, because even in 25.2.0, using `MessagingStyle` with the "v4" builder does not show anything in devices with API < 24.